# Where can I find good resources for learning Robotic Process Automation (RPA)?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, uiautomation

I'm looking for tutorials for learning RPA. I did a lot of google search but couldn't find anything thats useful. Please suggest me some useful tutorials or certifications from where I can learn RPA.

Comment: Did you tried Google?

Answer (score 1):

A software 'robot' is a software application that replicates the actions of a human being interacting with the user interface of a computer system. For example, the execution of data entry into a SAP system - or indeed a full end-to-end business process - would be a typical activity for a software robot. The software robot operates on the user interface (UI) in the same way that a human would; this is a significant departure from traditional forms of IT integration which have historically been based on Application Programming Interfaces (or APIs) - that is to say, machine-to-machine forms of communication based on data layers which operate at an architectural layer beneath the UI... says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotic_process_automation).

...in other words, RPA is nothing else than a marketing term for web automation and macro recorder software. The term is mostly used by vendors of (usually expensive) automation software that targets the enterprise market. A related term is BPO - Business Process Automation.

But with regards to software, from web testing/web automation software like Selenium or Kantu to desktop automation software like AHK or Sikuli - these are all Robotic process automation (RPA) tools. So anyone that knows how to use AHK is also an RPA expert.

So if you want to learn the technical side of RPA, learn one or more of these automation tools. For the business side, some MBA related literature can be interesting.

Comment: Years of working in selenium, and now looking at RPA (UIPath, Automation Anywhere).  It's .... a different approach.  Having to relearn really. Can see some overlap, but it's less about testing, and more about replacing a business process.